# Removing fields from output FeatureSet in ArcPy for geoprocessing service?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

The geoprocessing service runs a script that is trying to output a FeatureLayer or a FeatureSet that will contains a selection with only some fields of the original FeatureClass.

**I dont want to copy the FeatureLayer into a new FeatureClass, because I need to preserve selected features OBJECTID.**

I have try to use the FieldInfo paramater to put some fields to "HIDDEN" but in the REST output those fields appear anyway.

As I only need the output in json format, my second attempt was to load the FeatureLayer in a FeatureSet, then, I remove the unwanted fields directly by formatting the json (see below).

```
import arcpy
import json

codeCs = arcpy.getParameter(0)
outFields = arcpy.getParameter(1)
expression = u"CODECS = '{}'".format(codeCs)
result = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(SOURCE_FC, "temp_lyr", where_clause=expression)
fSet = arcpy.FeatureSet()
fSet.load(result)
desc = arcpy.Describe(fSet)
esriJson = json.loads(desc.pjson)

fields = esriJson["fields"]
for field in fields[:]:
    if field["name"] not in outFields and field["name"] not in SOURCE_REQUIRED_FIELDS or field["name"] in SOURCE_HIDDEN_FIELDS:
        fields.remove(field)
        for idx, feat in enumerate(esriJson["features"][:]):
            del esriJson["features"][idx]["attributes"][field["name"]]

arcpy.SetParameter(2, json.dumps(esriJon))
```

This solution works, but it seems over-complicated to me. Anybody have an idea how I could remove some fields from a FeatureLayer?

Comment: Unless you're working with thousands of records, I'd suggest the easy solution:  copy features on your selected layer, then run DeleteField and return the output of that.

Comment: I cant do that because the features OID wont be the same

Comment: @BelowtheRadar From my experience I would recommend you use a different ID field so that you're not so reliant on the ObjectID.  Using the OID can cause problems.

Comment: I think the way you've done is faster than copy features and deleteField. I have little experience with arcpy, but with python gdal deleting fields from a shapefile attribute table is superfast. Also you can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

Comment: @Midavalo good advice, I decided to use a Guid field instead of OID. This way  I can copy the features into a in_memory FeatureClass and then delete the unwanted fields, keeping the Guid field for reference.